# Material-UI Accordion (formerly ExpansionTable) component won't import

Tags: reactjs, import, material-ui

I am building an app using `Material-UI`, so far so good.
I am trying to build a component using an `Accordion` component, but i am getting an error when trying to import it:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Accordion' in [path]
```

I have tried to import it both through a default and named imports, but the result is the same.

the component:

```
import React from 'react';
//  import {
//     Accordion,
//     AccordionSummary,
//     AccordionDetails
//  } from '@material-ui/core';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';


const JobCard = () => {

    return(
        <Accordion expanded={true}>
            <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            >
                test
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
                test
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    );
}

export default JobCard;
```

All my other components are working fine with imported Material-UI components.

Am i missing something here that i am doing wrong? Did anyone encounter such an issue?

Comment: Are you tried to reinstall `@material-ui/core` or restart web-server? :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ExpansionPanel has been [renamed to Accordion](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21494) . With your error, it looks like you are using material-ui-core version `4.10.2` (or below).

**Use material-ui-core version `4.11.0` or higher**.

[Working demo of your code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-accordion-import-issue-fixed-zsy5q)

Answer (score 9):

Install Material UI Core

`npm i @material-ui/core`

So , it will be  `@material-ui/core@4.11.0`

Then, its working. Have fun!!

Comment: Or `npm install @material-ui/core@latest`

Answer (score 2):

I had basically the same issue. Error was:

"Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore'"

After installing the following:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
"avatar": "^0.1.0",
"clsx": "^1.1.1",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"material-ui": "^0.20.2",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-ga": "^2.7.0",
"react-scripts": "1.0.17"
```

I ran `npm update` and ALL WAS GOOD :)

Comment: Keep in mind many of those components were already installed. The new ones I installed based on the error are: the 3 materialize ones, avatar, and clsx. Then npm update brought these two react components

Comment: Yes It's working good after I have updated @material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",

Answer (score 1):

The name of `Accordion` has been changed to `ExpansionPanel` lately, So import like this:

```
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
```

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI Accordion (formerly ExpansionTable) component won't import because it's has been renamed, so its update issue, so to update material ui and other packages in your folder run the command

```
npm outdated
```

The outdated dependencies will be listed out

npm update

or

```
npm update  "react" "react-dom"
```

to update specific package, after that run this command to install specific package

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

or

```
npm install
```

to install all packages